# Calculate electric field from wire with AC current through

Tags: electromagnetism, safety

Here an experiment picture

[image]

The wire(with some resistance) connected to 220 V 60 Hz AC voltage source. The peak current through wire is 0,3 A

How to calculate mean, or at least peak electric field strength value at some point from wire?

I have the next plan:

1. Consider the dynamics (of current, em wave, etc.) as a series of statics.
2. Find magnetic induction value, using Bio-Savant formula for few currents value.
3. Considering, that I know how fast current(and hence magnetic field) changes (half period is 1/60/2 seconds), I can calculate the $$\dfrac{dB}{dt}$$
4. From first Maxwell's equation get **rot E**
5. Hope that, having rot E value, the actual E value can be funded, because my vector algebra is bad..

Is my plan good? How to calculate electric field near wire with AC current throught  ?

Comment: since the loop cancels it’s “line field”, you are just measuring near-field fringe effects. Falstad main site has EM 2D and 3D with slice plots for ratiometric E field visualization.  you are measuring a 3D fringe effect.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, "near field" situated about 1 wavelength distance, i.e. 5000000 meters?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, and why cancels? There should be phase-shift interference because of distance between loop wires but not absolute canceling. No?

Comment: Near field to gradient around the narrow loop as the loop cancels in the same plane except for leakage

Comment: Recall the properties of a field from a point , line and plane source.  And in the same plane there is a null or weak stray E field, not BH field

Comment: The loop is strongest within the orthogonal direction of the loop centre within the longest dimension of the loop , long after which it looks like a point source

Comment: "Near field" means **within** about 1 wavelength, and the less distance the "nearer" the field.  Basically, at 60Hz, if it fits in a room (or even an aircraft hanger), you can just do the calculation for the peak current as if it were DC, and then multiply all your results by \$\sin 2 \pi (60 \mathrm{Hz}) t\$.

Comment: Do you want to compute a displacement current in some circuit node? Use the wire-wire coupling model to gain a general understanding of the Efield flux severity. Once you know the wire-wire capacitance, use I = C * dV/dT to compute the current at frequency F. Then, if you know the circuit impedance at "F", simply multiple Z  * I to compute the injected voltage. For some topologies, plane-to-plane coupling may be accurate enough.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I want to calculate the electric field out of wire, in some distance from it. I know the current, it is 0.3 A, I don't need to calculate it